# Get binding name in KnockoutJS binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have following:

```
<div data-bind="liveEditor: PropertyNameINeed"></div>
```

How do I get the name "PropertyNameINeed" with jQuery?

Is there better solution than that one?
https://www.wimpyprogrammer.com/get-bound-property-name-in-a-knockoutjs-custom-binding/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you,

```
var bindingText = $("#xyz").data('bind');

bindingText = bindingText.split(":"); //split the string w.r.t :
bindingText = bindingText[1]; // get 2nd string from an array
bindingText = bindingText.replace(' ', '') //Remove space from the string

console.log(bindingText);
```

Comment: Thanks... Or maybe there is a solution from KnockoutJS?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand *why* you would need to do this, but it's still an interesting problem to solve.

I thought of a solution that involves 'extending' the binding you're interested in. You'll have to be careful not to change its behavior...

The best way to explain my approach is through an example:

```js
// In this example, I want to access all properties bound via a `text` binding.
// I want to be able to retreive information about the binding using a HTMLElement

// Here, we'll store our binding information
var textBinds = [];

// This function returns an object from the `textBinds` array 
// based on a matching `element` property
var getTextBindingValueForElement = function(element) {
  return textBinds.find(function(b) {
    return b.element === element;
  });
};


// For this example we're tapping in to the `text` binding. If you're only watching
// custom bindings, it might be better to call a helper function in their init

// Store a reference to knockout's original `text` binding's `init` method:
var og = ko.bindingHandlers.text.init;

// Extend the method:
ko.bindingHandlers.text.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm) {
  // Loop through all of the viewmodel's properties to find the property
  // that matches the current value.
  // Note: if the value is a primitive (number, str, bool, null, etc.), this will
  // return the first match. So it ONLY WORKS FOR OBJECTS/FUNCTIONS
  var value = valueAccessor();
  var prop = Object.keys(vm).find(function(key) {
    return vm[key] === value;
  });

  // We're storing element, prop and value in a plain object
  textBinds.push({
    element: element,
    prop: prop,
    value: value
  });

  // This ensures the old behavior still works
  return og.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Now, we can access the bound `text` property via the element inside an
// ordinary jQuery click listener
$(".js-onClick").click(function() {
  var bindData = getTextBindingValueForElement(this);
  console.log("Prop: " + bindData.prop);
  console.log("Val: " + bindData.value());
});


ko.applyBindings({
  testLabel: ko.observable("Hello world")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="js-onClick" data-bind="text: testLabel"></div>
```

Advantages of this approach:

- No regex
- Let's you store an actual reference to the data-bound value (`value` in the example code). I don't really understand why you'd need the property name...

Limitations:

- Does not work if the property contains a primitive

Comment: The approach is to avoid more than one field being editable at time. As result it will send/save an object/data to server whereas user goes to next field by pressing tab button.

Comment: If that's the use case, I'd skip all of this code and use the `event` binding instead of enabling/disabling form elements via jQuery.

Comment: Have you used JIRA before? I've done something similarly to theirs implementation. In other words I've created et editable view - it looks nicer and takes less place.